# Creating duplicate rankings with window function in mysql

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I have a table like below:

| product | country | group | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | c1 | g1 | 5 |
| p1 | c1 | g2 | 6 |
| p1 | c2 | g1 | 3 |
| p1 | c2 | g2 | 22 |
| p1 | c3 | g1 | 1 |
| p1 | c3 | g2 | 6 |

I want to rank them considering the sum in value column for every product-country combination. So in this case, the updated table should be like this:

| product | country | group | value | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | c1 | g1 | 5 | 2 |
| p1 | c1 | g2 | 6 | 2 |
| p1 | c2 | g1 | 3 | 1 |
| p1 | c2 | g2 | 22 | 1 |
| p1 | c3 | g1 | 1 | 3 |
| p1 | c3 | g2 | 6 | 3 |

p1-c1 combination will have the 2nd seed because 5+6 in the value column is higher than 7 (1+6) and lower than 25 (22+3). I used `dense_rank() over (partition by product, country order by value)` but it didn't work. How can I create the above ranking using mysql?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `SUM()` window function in a subquery to get the total value for each product, country combination and then `DENSE_RANK()` to rank the totals:

```
select product, country, `group`, value,
       dense_rank() over (order by total desc) rnk  
from (
  select *, sum(value) over (partition by product, country) total
  from tablename
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf6533ded689f262576a8aaffbcc8e8c).